# Trying to access array offset on value of type null arrojado por la funcion file_exist

Tags: php, php7

Desarrollando un sistema de ruteo mvc, encontré que en linea de la función `file_exist` me arrojaba el siguiente **Notice**

`$url` es un array donde su valor es el valor actual de la url.

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

```
<?php
...
...

$url = $this->parseUrl();

if(file_exists("../app/controllers/" . $url[0] . ".php")){
   $this->controller = $url[0];
   unset($url[0]);
}

require_once "../app/controllers/" . $this->controller . ".php";

...
...

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es implementar un `isset()` a este array. Este problema resulta en que versiones anteriores de php7 no se era tan estricto al momento de acceder, en este caso al valor de un array, que realmente no se sabe si esta o no esta asignado su valor.

Implementado en código, la solución queda así:

```
<?php
...
...
        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if(isset($url[0])){
            if(file_exists("../app/controllers/" . $url[0] . ".php")){
                $this->controller = $url[0];
                unset($url[0]);
            }
        }

        require_once "../app/controllers/" . $this->controller . ".php";
...
...
?>
```